# html_entity_decode(): charset `ASCII' not supported

Tags: php, warnings

I've got my php.log (a log for PHP errors) being filled up every day with the following line:

> PHP Warning:  html_entity_decode(): charset ASCII not supported, assuming iso-8859-1 in /....php on line 149

Line #149 looks like:

```
$html = html_entity_decode($html, ENT_QUOTES, mb_detect_encoding($html));
```

The usage of `html_entity_decode()` is according to php.net, so what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking for granted that [mb_detect_encoding()](http://php.net/mb_detect_encoding) is a tool to figure out what encoding a text is using. In fact it isn't. It's impossible to accomplish automated encoding detection and that function does not even try.

You got `ASCII`. Then asked PHP to decode HTML entities to US-ASCII.
Since good old 7-bit US-ASCII can hardly store about a hundred printable characters, that's mostly an impossible task.

The proper way to determine the encoding of HTML is:

1. Web server's `Content-Type` header, if available:

   ```
   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
   ```
2. HTML meta tags otherwise:

   ```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   ```

Comment: thanks. However what should I do to to the existing code in order to dodge this error? It's an old project and I would like to change it as little as possible. would it be a good idea: `$code = (mb_detect_encoding($html) == 'ASCII') ? 'UTF-8' : mb_detect_encoding($html);     $html = html_entity_decode($html, ENT_QUOTES, $code);`

Comment: Did you really follow the link to the manual page for `mb_detect_encoding()`? In most systems it'll only return `ASCII` or `UTF-8` ([demo](https://3v4l.org/c3WoM)) so you'd basically be hard-coding `UTF-8` in a really convoluted way. The question is lacking all context, I can't say what `$html` is or comes from, I don't know why you need to detect encoding that way.

Comment: $html is an article from a web site which is being decoded and parsed (trimmed from tags to make an xml rss file). Sadly, I really don't understand the solution then.

Comment: Computers are digital devices that only understand ones and zeroes (let's put it that way). If all you have is `00010111` there's no way to say what encoding it's using—it could be any. That's why web sites actually declare the encoding they are using so you don't need to guess.